# Can't access @Property from other class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm having trouble accessing some variables in my program.

I have one class called MainMenu.

In the .h file I have declared 2 properties as follows:

```
MainMenu.h:
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSWindow *theMainWindow;
```

In another class file, I want to be able to access these 2 variables, current I am using the following code in the other .h class file which does not work, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
AppDelegate.m:
MainMenu *theMainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] init];
[theMainMenu switchViews:theMainMenu.theMainWindow:theMainMenu.mainView];
```

Here I create an object of the MainMenu class, and invoke a method called 'switchViews' in its definition, I then want to pass it the 2 variables which I'm having trouble accessing.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance everyone.

EDIT: 'switchViews' method shown below:

```
- (void)switchViews:(NSWindow*)mainWindow:(NSView*)newView {
    NSView *dummyView;
    [mainWindow setContentView:dummyView];
    [mainWindow setContentSize:newView.frame.size];
    [mainWindow setContentView:newView];
}
```

Comment: The syntax you are using to call switchViews is incorrect. How is switchViews declared?

Comment: i've added the method to my post

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Compilation error? Runtime error?

Comment: No compilation or runtime errors, it just doesn't pass the variables to the method call, i said this in the post

Comment: are you sure that `theMainMenu.theMainWindow` and `theMainMenu.mainView` are not null?

Comment: i have connected them with IB, so i dont think they're null

Comment: @Cristian please check the values of these properties after the alloc-init. If I'm not mistaken they will get some values in viewWillAppear method. And for the next comments please refer to the person(write @ and the nick), that will give a notification to that user that he has a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is one of 2 different instances of your MainMenu class.  If you hooked up your IBOutlets, you must have a blue cube in IB set to your MainMenu class, correct?  However, when you alloc init one in your app delegate, that creates another instance of MainMenu that doesn't have those properties connected to anything.  Instead, you should also have a blue cube in IB set to your app delegate, and have an IBOutlet in that class that you connect to the MainMenu blue cube in IB.

Answer (score 0):

This might be silly, but did you remember to link your NSWindow and NSView in Interface Builder? Or are you at least manually instantiating them?

My best guess is (assuming there is a MainMenu.xib somewhere), that when you call `init`, it object is inited but not necessarily loaded. You should try to call your switchViews method in your controllers `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method to be sure it is all loaded.

Comment: Not silly, all help appreciated. Everything's linked up properly

Comment: Where in AppDelegate.m are you calling that method from?

Comment: applicationDidFinishLaunching()

Comment: it's not an issue with the method, if i re-create the variables in the AppDelegate class it works perfectly. I just wish to not have to re-set these variables, instead access the ones set in the MainMenu class