# Objective-c Getting variable from another classe

Tags: objective-c, class, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to access object of other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646432/unable-to-access-object-of-other-class)

I've been working on a little project just to increase my comprehension of the objective-c syntaxe and functionalities but I'm stuck in my own project and can't find the answer.

First I've got two classes and in my main one I have declare a object of my other class so I can use the functions from my other class. This is how I did it (I just wrote the thing that I thought were necessary:

```
.h of my main class
import myOtherClass

@interface PkmViewController : UIViewController

    @property Pokemon * nomDePokemon;

.m of my main class
import myOtherClass

@synthesize nomDePokemon;

int nbDef = [nomDePokemon calculerUnNombrePourLaDefense];

.h of my other class

@interface Pokemon : NSObject

  @property int defencePoints;

-(int)calculerUnNombrePourLaDefense;

.m of my other class

@synthesize defencePoints;

-(int)calculerUnNombrePourLaDefense
{
    int nombrerandom = arc4random() % 45;
    return nombrerandom;
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in my main class to see what number is taken from the function, it always gives me 0. And when I put this section in my other class it works but I want to keep it in another class to improve my skills. Someone can explain me how to do it please?

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198662/cant-access-property-from-other-class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295560/accessing-property-of-other-class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632764/access-to-property-of-another-class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646432/unable-to-access-object-of-other-class and a hundred others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't actually assigned an instance of Pokemon to your `nomDePokemon` variable. This means that instead of a Pokemon object, the variable contains `nil`, which returns `nil` or `0` in response to any message you send it. To solve the problem, create a Pokemon.

Comment: I thought by doing property Pokemon * nomDePokemon it would create a Pokemon. Then how would you do that?

Comment: @Gab: Nope, that just declares a variable that can hold a Pokemon. Creating an object is normally done with something like `[[Pokemon alloc] init]`. If you haven't heard about this sort of stuff yet, I'd recommend reading an intro to Objective-C/Cocoa programming, such as Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html). It's really fundamental and you're going to find yourself frequently confused if you don't know it.

Comment: It's okay I'm a retard haha. For those who would find this useful I just did : nomDePokemon = [[Pokemon alloc] init]. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks Chuck I just remembered in the same time you wrote me :)