# Using variable value from another class Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, class, variables

I know this has been posted many times but I cannot get it to work, there are no errors in my code (found by Xcode), but what I'm trying to do isn't working.

1- Setup: I have 2 classes, `ViewController (UIViewController)` and `GraphView (UIView)`

2- What I am trying to do: I have a BOOL type variable `plotPressedVC` in ViewController that takes an initial value `NO`. 
Once a button is pressed (this `IBAction` is located in the ViewController.m file) `plotPressedVC = YES`. From this, in my GraphView.m file I have an `if` statement whose condition is met if `pressed = YES`.

3- My code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController  {
    @public BOOL plotPressedVC;
}

- (IBAction)plot:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GraphView.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    plotPressedVC = YES;
}

- (IBAction)plot:(id)sender {
    plotPressedVC = YES;

    GraphView *plotPress = [[GraphView alloc] init];
    plotPress.plotPressed = plotPressedVC;
}

@end
```

**GraphView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface GraphView : UIView {
    BOOL plotPressed;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL plotPressed;

@end
```

**GraphView.m**

```
#import "GraphView.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation GraphView

- (void)drawLineGraphWithContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

    if (plotPressed == YES) {
        NSLog(@"yep");    
    }

    // Other code that I want to be in if statement
}

@end
```

4- Question: What have I done wrong for the if statement's condition to not have been met when pushing the button `plot`?

**EDIT**: added `NSlog` at the end of the `plot` action, I am getting values 80, -64, -128...

```
- (IBAction)plot:(id)sender {

    plotPressedVC = YES;

    NSLog(@"%hhd",plotPressedVC);

    GraphView *plotPress = [[GraphView alloc] init];
    plotPress.plotPressed = plotPressedVC;

    NSLog(@"%hhd",plotPress);

}
```

New Question: How come plotPress is receiving other numbers than 0 or 1?

Comment: I edited the code, I added an NSLog, and it's not giving me BOOL values. I think that's why, I will edit the question

Comment: Your NSLog is logging the value of the graph view. It should say NSLog(@"%d",plotPress.plotPressed), but that isn't the problem with your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-c Getting variable from another classe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539183/objective-c-getting-variable-from-another-classe)

Comment: @HotLicks I know this question has been asked before but no solution has gotten me to the answer

Comment: That's odd, because your problem is the classical one -- creating an object and expecting it to miraculously communicate with other objects of it's class.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry that I started coding literally 9 days ago and I've never heard of anything revolving around programming until then. Just because you know a lot in this domain doesn't mean you have to comment on it, just leave it and don't answer if you don't want to help

Comment: If you started coding 9 days ago, **what the heck are you doing working with Objective-C??**  You should start with something like Java, and go through a good tutorial -- the world can wait a few weeks for that great viral app you're planning to write.

Comment: I'm making an app for Team Canada Olympics... So it's not going to be viral, and it could wait, you're right, but not that long.  I was asked to do so by the NRC as a co-op placement because they trust my learning abilities. So before you go out and say what I'm doing is useless, get your facts straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been asked many times and it usually has the same answer.

The problem is here:

```
GraphView *plotPress = [[GraphView alloc] init];
plotPress.plotPressed = plotPressedVC;
```

Here you create a new graph view, set the value on it, and then do nothing else with it. You need to have an outlet or property to the *existing* graph view and set the `plotPressed` value on that.

Currently that graph view is never added to another view, and under ARC will be immediately deallocated at the end of the method.

Comment: how do I create a property to the existing GraphView ? I thought `plotPressed` was the property?

Comment: If you've created the layout in interface builder, you need to make an outlet and connect it up. There are hundreds of tutorials out there.

Comment: @KChockey - Thought is required.

Comment: @jrturton alright I'll try to make the outlet to the existing graphview, thank you.